# Create custom OSM map file

Tags: openstreetmap, android

I develop an Android app that uses [Mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge) to display OSM maps. I could use a [pre-built map](http://download.mapsforge.org/maps) in the [MapsForge file format](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Specification-Binary-Map-File.md) but that makes my APK file to big and I only need a small part of my country anyway.

How can I only get a small rectangle part of the world of OSM and put it in a map file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ready-to-go solution can be the web service of http://extract.bbbike.org/,
there you can define a boundingbox on an online map and choose many different output formats for OSM based maps. They also have mapsforge format there.

Have not tried on my own so far, so I cannot give any information about size limit for downloads, like a whole continent or similar

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you require the `.OSM` format.

Start by downloading the `Planet.osm` file, and use the program Osmconvert.

The command `osmconvert planet-160104.osm -b=-144,20,-50,90 -o=subset.osm` will subset to a square AOI as specified.

See more info [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) and specifically for subsetting the dataset [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Planet_.osm_-.3E_clipped_.osm).

Comment: I guess I could do it with the Argentina map also? Since I can't download 46GB.

Comment: Yes, you could also use a Argentina.osm file, if you had that available.

Comment: I think the Mapsforge file format is somewhat different than OSM: https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Specification-Binary-Map-File.md

Comment: @juergend - Then follow the guide here https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md and convert your subsetted .osm file into the Mapforge format.

Comment: I used OSMosis to convert a OSM file to a Mapsforge MAP and did only take a part of the map in the process with: `.\bin\osmosis.bat --rb c:\\argentina.osm.pbf --mw c:\\argentina.map bbox=-27.12881324,-55.20423889,-26.50621777,-54.56977844`

Answer (score 0):

You could try DogSheep Customizable Maps app. It lets you download maps by cutting it with a bounding box. The app uses MapsForge, so you could grab the map.map file from the download/dog_sheep/map_name directory, where map_name is the name you gave to the map when you downloaded it.